# Use redundant NAS drive as External HDD for laptop

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas

I have swapped out 1 of my 3.5" SATA QNAP 4TB WD Red NAS drives and replaced it with an 8 TB drive. Now I would like to use the replaced disk inside an HDD enclosure and use it on my laptop as External HDD. When I connect the HDD enclosure to my laptop, it says I need to format the disk. And displays error "the volume does not contain a recognised file system". Is that expected, and what is the solution that allows me to maintain the data on the HDD? Thanks

Comment: Don't know much about NASes, but if it was formatted with some Linux filesystem (e.g. ext4), then it is expected if you are now accessing it on Windows. (And WSL is one way to make the files available for access.) Another possibility is (even if it was formatted with NTFS or exFAT) because the enclosure has firmware that "groups" 512-byte logical blocks and present the groups as 4096-byte logical blocks to the OS, which makes the partition table "wrong". (No point in trying to "fix" it though since the metadata in the filesystem would be "wrong" as well.)

Comment: Actually, if it's the former case, the partition shouldn't be treated as a volume and be getting a drive letter (which in turn allows / asks you to format it), unless your NAS used a Windows partition type code / GUID even when it actually formatted it with a Linux filesystem...

Comment: Hi @TomYan, the QNAP OS is indeed Linux-based, so that sounds about right. And you are also correct that laptop's Windows OS assigned a letter to the drive (actually many different letters - from F to J). What I get from your answer, is that there is no point to try and retain the contents of this HDD, but rather just format it and start as a fresh HDD?

Comment: If you don't need to salvage the contents, formatting the disk will make your life *much* simpler.

Comment: @user80 well, my point is, if it's the former case (filesystem type reason), then is really up to you. While you can use the drive without reformatting with WSL, it would still be more or less inconvenient, so I'd say you probably want to maybe move the data out to somewhere else with the help of WSL, and then just reformat it (and move the data back). If it's the latter case (logical block "grouping"), I'd say you should really consider using another enclosure that does not do that (regardless of whether you mind reformatting the drive).

Comment: IMHO this kind of enclosure makes thing really ugly, because once you format your drive in one of them, you'll need to stick with this kind of enclosure if you want to retain your data.